# Initialize member reference with default value

Tags: c++, constructor, default-arguments

I have a class with a `std::vector const&` member which shall be set through the constructor. However, it should also be possible to omit this parameter in the constructor and let the member be initialized by a default value.

Example Code:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(int a, const std::vector<int> &v = {42,42,42}) : vec(v){}

  const std::vector<int> &vec;
};

int main(void) {

  std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};

  MyClass c1(1,a);              // c1.vec = 1,2,3
  MyClass c2(1);                // c2.vec = randomStuff
                                // should actually be 42,42,42
}
```

If I change the initialization to:

```
MyClass(int a, const std::vector<int> &v = *(new std::vector<int>{42,42,42})) : vec(v){}
```

Everything works fine since the temporary vector is not deleted when going out of scope. However, this doesn't feel right and look memory leaky. Is there a saner way to achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: Note that it doesn't just *look* memory leaky, it does actually leak memory.

Comment: Are you sure holding a *reference* member is really what you want to do? Make sure you have your object lifetimes completely straight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the default argument as a static data member of your class:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  MyClass(int a, const std::vector<int> &v = defaultVec) : vec(v){}

  const std::vector<int> &vec;

 private:
  static const std::vector<int> defaultVec;
};

const std::vector<int> MyClass:defaultVec{42, 42, 42};
```

To keep the class header-only, you can also use a static variable in a static member function instead:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  MyClass(int a, const std::vector<int> &v = defaultVec()) : vec(v){}

  const std::vector<int> &vec;

 private:
  static const std::vector<int>& defaultVec()
  {
   static const std::vector<int> v {42, 42, 42};
   return v;
  }
};
```

Note that either way, the vector used as the default argument has to have static storage duration, so that it remains valid after the constructor finishes running.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved with an explanation of why a static member is required, and maybe something about the risks and consequences of reference type members (such as preventing assignment and move semantics and lifetime management issues).

Comment: Consider inline variables (or pre-C++17 tricks) to allow the class to be header-only (as original class was)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux agree with explanation of static, disagree with reference part - OP already uses a reference, we have no reason to assume they are unsure about potential pitfalls.